# ¿Como poner signo de $ en un datagridview en una columna de costos en visual studio 2010?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, vba, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2010

Hola espero puedan ayudarme, habrá alguna manera de formatear una columna de un datagridview en visual para que se se visualice el signo de pesos $, ya que tengo una columna de costos y el datagridview lo exporto a excel, con el siguiente codigo me funciona para un textbox pero no sé para un datagridview

```
TXTDESTAJO.Text = Format(TotalDestajo, "$ #0.00")
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer algo como esto:

```
DataGridView1.Columns(1).DefaultCellStyle.FormatProvider = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US")
DataGridView1.Columns(1).DefaultCellStyle.Format = "C2"
```

Esto debería funcionar, debe tomar en cuenta que el valor debe ser `decimal`, `double`, si es de tipo texto este tipo de formato no funcionará.

Fuente:

> - [Cadenas con formato numérico estándar](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/dwhawy9k(v=vs.100)?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235)
> - [Procedimiento para dar formato a datos en el control DataGridView de formularios Windows Forms](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-format-data-in-the-windows-forms-datagridview-control?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235)
> - [Tabla CultureInfo](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/commerce-server/ee825488(v=cs.20)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

**EDITADA**

Si se fija inicialmente su pregunta no menciona nada sobre Exportar Datos a Excel, sin embargo lo que necesita para lograr esto es [Range.NumberFormat](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.numberformat?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=excel-pia), `Currency $#,##0.00;[Red]$#,##0.00`, algo como esto:

```
range.Cells(0,2).EntireColumn.NumberFormat = "$#,##0.00";
```

Para más información al respecto, consulte el siguiente enlace:

> - [¿Cuáles son las opciones de .NumberFormat en Excel VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20648149/8933039)

Comment: Gracias, ya me pone el signo de $ en el datagridview pero al exportarlo a excel me sigue saliendo en decimal es decir, en datagridview me aparece $5.00 y en excel solo 5.00

Comment: He editado la respuesta, revise la información adicional.